# This app requires iOS 6

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, ios6, xcode4.5

Recently app-store is successfully approved my iOS application. My application  is cocos2dbox2d application

Application details:

1. Development target is 4.3
2. Xcode 4.5
3. Universal app
4. Default-568h@2x.png added
5. Base SDK - iOS6.0
6. Valid Architectures - armv7
7. Build Active ArchitectureOnly  - NO

This is my application Build settings. OK, Now i am trying to install my application in iOS5.1 ipad. It showing Alert message, Message is This app requires iOS6.

Why it is happen?  Any one help me...

Thanks Advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that in both, your project's settings and target setting, iOS Deployment Target is same, coz target overwrite the project's settings, means if you set you deployment target to 5.1 in Project settings whereas in Target's setting it's selected 6.0, then project setting for deployment target isn't used instead Xcode uses the target's settings